# Display badge number in Android/Ios using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing an hybrid application with  cordova .I want to display notifications count in the application icon same as below image after recieving a notification from the APNS/FCM. I am using cordova-plugin-fcm and cordova-plugin-badge plugins.

code :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {     
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.hasPermission(function (granted) {
    });

    cordova.plugins.notification.badge.registerPermission(function (hasPermission) {
    });

    // switch on 'auto clear'
    cordova.plugins.notification.badge.configure({
    autoClear: true
    }); 
//FCMPlugin.getToken( successCallback(token), errorCallback(err) ); 
    //Keep in mind the function will return null if the token has not been established yet. 
    FCMPlugin.getToken(
    function(token){            
        console.log("token "+token);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
    }
    )

    //FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic( topic, successCallback(msg), errorCallback(err) ); 
    //All devices are subscribed automatically to 'all' and 'ios' or 'android' topic respectively. 
    //Must match the following regular expression: "[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}". 
    FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('all');

    //FCMPlugin.onNotification( onNotificationCallback(data), successCallback(msg), errorCallback(err) )
    //Here you define your application behaviour based on the notification data.

    FCMPlugin.onNotification(
    function(data){     
        //increase the badge        
        cordova.plugins.notification.badge.increase();
        if(data.wasTapped){
        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.              

        }else{
        //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.             
        }
    },
    function(msg){
    console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);         
    },
    function(err){
        console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
    }
    );}
```

[Image with badge !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwfk2.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to send 2 distinct FCM messages.

First one without notification, with a payload like this:

```
{
  "data":{
    "badge":"true",
  },
    "to":"/topics/all",
    "priority":"high"
}
```

This will trigger onMessageReceived in MyFirebaseMessagingService.java, then pushes the payload to FCMPlugin.onNotification() callback.

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    if(data.badge == "true"){
        cordova.plugins.notification.badge.increase();
    }
});
```

By doing this, you will increase the badge number. 
Then, you send the notification with a payload like this:

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
    "to":"/topics/all",
    "priority":"high"
}
```

This way you will get the message in the notifications tray. I also recommend setting `cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(0)` onDeviceReady and onResume events so that the badge number is cleared after app comes to foreground.